# Google maps snap-to-road draw in bad order

Tags: google-maps

When I get a response from https://roads.googleapis.com/v1/snapToRoads the snaped coordinates are not in order - I mean instead of following the road steps go forward 3 points and then back again.

Maybe the image can explain better. In the picture the road is jumping from 1 to 4, then return to 3.

[image]

Comment: What does the request look like?  Or at least a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the request that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: the request is with this code:

Comment: Please edit your question to include the requested information, don't try to reply with code in the comments.